# prove that a Lie algebra is semisimple

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let
$$J_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$J=\begin{pmatrix}
0_3 & J_3 \\
J_3 & 0_3 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Consider the Lie algebra $L=\{x \in gl(6,\mathbb{C})|^txJ+Jx=0\}$
I have to prove that $L$ is semisimple and find a a maximal total subalgebra $H$ of $L$.
I now what a semisimple Lie algebra is and I know a series of equivalent condition ($Rad L=0$, killing form non degenerate, no abelian ideals). But I don’t know how to use this condition.  In general how can I prove that a Lie algebra is semisimple?

Comment: The Killing form is nondegenerate, see the duplicate. For this, it is enough to consider the trace form $(x,y)\mapsto tr(xy)$. It is nondegenerate.